# Convert image to gray scale

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiimageview

In my application I'm having one `UIImageView`, there is one `UIView` of clear background color on top of this `UIImageView`.

I'm using `UIBezierPath` to free hand drawing on this UIView so that it appears user is drawing on the `UIImage` of `UIImageView`.

I'm adding transparency to the `UIBezierPath` color.

My question is when I initially load `UIImage` in `UIImageView` how to make look that `UIImage` is of gray scale and when user moves his finger on the screen the original color of the `UIImage` is showed to the user?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to use Core Image, and write your own Core Image filter that operates on the color image. By setting a few properties on the filter, it would know to draw some section in color but convert the other areas to gray scale.

That said this is not a trivial work item. You may be able to hack something else together but it will probably be jerky and not smooth. The Core Image filter works at the same level Core Animation does (near the GPU) so it will work very well if you go that way.

Comment: First i tried with Core image filter but it was very slow so i applied this image view as content view of uiview so that when drawn on uiview it appears to be on image.

Comment: Well, my point was that the lower view would have the filter and you would continue to use the view located above to deal with the drawing.  You wrote your filter using the vector instructions?

Comment: Exactly - you are doing the work in the drawrect, which is not what you would do using a Core Image filter. If you want fast and smooth, you will have to spend the time to do a real filter using the vector language. Apple has many examples of such a thing, but you will have to dedicate time to do this.

Answer (score 0):

On touch, call this function which returns you grey scaled image. On touches ended, set your original image for UIImageView.

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithGrayScaleImage:(UIImage*)inputImg
{   
//Creating image rectangle
//CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, inputImg.size.width / (CGFloat)[inputImg scale], inputImg.size.height / (CGFloat)[inputImg scale]);
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, inputImg.size.width, inputImg.size.height);

//Allocating memory for pixels
int width = imageRect.size.width;
int height = imageRect.size.height;

uint32_t *pixels = (uint32_t*)malloc(width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));

//Clearing the memory to preserve any transparency.(Alpha)
memset(pixels, 0, width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));

//Creating a context with RGBA pixels
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, 8, width * sizeof(uint32_t), colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

//Drawing the bitmap to the context which will fill the pixels memory
CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, [inputImg CGImage]);

//Indices as ARGB or RGBA
const int RED = 1;
const int GREEN = 2;
const int BLUE = 3;

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        uint8_t* rgbaPixel = (uint8_t*)&pixels[y * width + x];

        //Calculating the grayScale value
        uint32_t grayPixel = 0.3 * rgbaPixel[RED] + 0.59 * rgbaPixel[GREEN] + 0.11 * rgbaPixel[BLUE];

        //Setting the pixel to gray
        rgbaPixel[RED] = grayPixel;
        rgbaPixel[GREEN] = grayPixel;
        rgbaPixel[BLUE] = grayPixel;
    }
}

//Creating new CGImage from the context with modified pixels
CGImageRef newCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

//Releasing resources to free up memory
CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
free(pixels);

//Creating UIImage for return value
//UIImage* newUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newCGImage scale:(CGFloat)[inputImg scale] orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
UIImage* newUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newCGImage];

//Releasing the CGImage
CGImageRelease(newCGImage);

return newUIImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i want to remove the grey color in touches moved method. In the above method it is using for loop for all the points in the view so it will get very slow. I have tried the above method. I want the effect as in color splurge application.